# Spy with colors Matlab

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, spy

With reference to this previous post 
[Getting different colors for different numbers using `spy` in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838900/getting-different-colors-for-different-numbers-using-spy-in-matlab)

where it was suggested the following in order to have different values of spy represented with different colors

```
spy(a,'k')
hold on
spy(a==10,'r')
spy(a==9,'b')
hold off
```

How can I do if I would like to use RGB definitions? For example having [ 0.6 0.2 0] for all elements =10 and [0.8 1 0] for all elements =9 instead of the already defined r, b and k etc?

The following does not work because all the Spy matrix will be of a certain color,

```
set(get(gca,'children'),'color',[0.6 0.2 0])
```

Thanks, 
M.

Comment: I suggest you look at the `scatter` function. I'm on my cell so I can't help you much more I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to the solution. `children` returns you three results for each of the three inputs, you must index it.

```
x=get(gca,'children')
set(x(1),'color',firstcolor)
set(x(2),'color',secondcolor)
set(x(3),'color',thirdcolor)
```